# Erro em site Joomla: 0 Invalid controller: name='', format='' joomla administrator

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Estou a tentar entrar na administração do meu site Joomla 3.0, mas estou a obter o seguinte erro:

> 0 Invalid controller: name='', format=''

Alguém me pode dar uma pista de como o resolver?

Answer (score 0):

@user40862, segundo o [link do fórum oficial do Joomla](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=709714), me parece que faltou incluir a *tag* do arquivo da *controller* no xml de configuração do componente:

```
<filename>controller.php</filename>
```